# Possible to combine several bz2 archives into one?

Tags: unix, compression, bzip2

I have several (27) huge (several GB each) bz2 archive files that I need combined into one bz2 archive.  Uncompressing them and then creating a new archive from what was just uncompressed is not an option for me, since compressed, all 27 files add up to about 100GB, and uncompressed it's about 5-6TB (yes that's TERAbytes lol).

Can this be done with some sort of script, or is there even another compression format that allows for this to be done (easier)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to burn a few days of CPU, here's one solution with the magical pipe facility of modern UNIX(R) operating systems:

```
bzip2 -dc file*.bz2 | bzip2 >resulting_file.bz2
```

... actually, grab lbzip2 **version 2.0**, and do the same, except with lbzip2, on a multicore:

```
lbzip2 -dc file*.bz2 | lbzip2 >resulting_file.bz2
```

Answer (score 36):

You can simply concatenate many bz2 files into single bz2 file, like that:

`$ cat file1.bz2 file2.bz2 file3.bz2 >resulting_file.bz2`

`bzip2` and other utilities like `lbzip2` will be able to decompress the resulting file as expected.

Comment: In fact, it works! From man bzip2:
`bunzip2 will correctly decompress a file which is the concatenation of two or more compressed files.  The result is the concatenation  of  the  corresponding  uncompressed  files. Integrity  testing (-t) of concatenated compressed files is also supported.`

Answer (score 3):

You should flip the question around - you should not try to decompress and then recompress the files, simply make a tar archive of all the separate files - tar is ideal as a container for the separate files.

```
tar cf tarofbzfiles.tar *.bz2
```

Comment: Actually I really do need one archive containing all the contents of the 27 archives, lol.  I'm pretty sure one archive containing 27 archives won't work for my purpose, unfortunately. :(

Comment: What type of file is the .bz2 archive? if it's a tar file, then it's possible to concatenate them. It would require a script chaining the uncompression of each of the archives into their own pipe/fifo that is used in a set of tar -A commands, which all conclude into a fifo that is piped through bzip2

Comment: I *think* each file is one single (huge) XML file.  I'm currently trying a command called bzcat like this: `bzcat *.bz2 > newfile.bz2`. I started it over an hour ago so we'll see how it goes...much later. :)

Comment: bzcat *.bz2 | bzip2 -c > newfile.bz2 - if you don't re-bzip2 the file you won't get the compression!!

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten @lacos's answer with the built in `bzcat` shorthand for `bzip2 -dc` and pipe back into `bzip2` as usual. Not any more correct than @lacos but a little bit slicker ;)

```
bzcat file*.bz2 | bzip2 >resulting_file.bz2
```